# "Java Date() returns date in UTC" - what does it actually mean?

Tags: java, date, gmt

My question might be trivial but I'm just looking for clarifications. I read somewhere in SO that Java's Date() is actually always in UTC time, how come when I create a Date() object and print it using toString(), it displays the local time. If this is not the right way to print it, what should it be so I would get the UTC time?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For formatting, you should really use a `DateFormat` implementation (e.g. `SimpleDateFormat`).  That will let you specify the time zone (and output format). `Date` itself has no concept of time zones - it represents an instant in time, using the "milliseconds since the Unix epoch" as storage. The `toString()` method just converts whatever instant is represented into a local time using the system default time zone.

Personally I'd advise moving away from the built-in date/time API entirely and using [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sf.net) as a far more sensible library.

Comment: yes, it was actually from your post that I came up with this question. For printing, yes I do use DateFormat. But how is "UTC" related to Date()? I couldn't find the connection and why it always displays local time, when I thought it should be UTC time (GMT+0)? Well, I know that Date() is just represents time elapsed since January 1, 1970...

Comment: @jasonline: The Unix epoch is defined to be midnight January 1st 1970 *in UTC*.

Comment: So I guess that's how the connection came up, and I shouldn't expect the UTC time to be displayed if I'm somewhere living in GMT+8 for example.

Comment: @jasonline: Not from `Date.toString`, no. As I say, use Joda instead :)

Answer (score 2):

> “Java Date() returns date in UTC” - what does it actually mean?

[UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) is the baseline against which we adjust the time-of-day around the globe.

Since the caveman days, noon, or 12:00, is when the sun is directly overhead. Of course, that means different moments in different places. Noon in Japan happens hours earlier than in Europe, and noon arrives even later in the Americas.

In the modern era, humans created [time zones](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones) where noon would apply to a wide swath of land, so wide that the sun may not be overhead simultaneously across all of it. So the sun, or [“solar time”](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solar_time), could no longer be used to define time. The modern time zone is defined as being a certain number of hours-minutes-seconds from the baseline.

What baseline? That baseline was arbitrarily chosen by the fate of history to be the latitude that runs through the [Royal Observatory, Greenwich](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Royal_Observatory,_Greenwich) in London, England, UK. Time zones to the east are a certain number of hours-minutes-seconds *ahead* of UTC, and to the west a certain number *behind* UTC. For example, India is five and half hours *ahead* of UTC, and Martinique in the Caribbean is four hours *behind* UTC.

If the offset is zero hours-minutes-seconds, then we say we are “at UTC” or “in UTC”.

> Java's Date() is actually always in UTC time

Yes, the `java.util.Date` class, despite its unfortunate name, represents a date with time-of-day with an offset-from-UTC of zero.

The `Date` class is now obsolete, by the way. The [`java.time.Instant`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) class is now used as its replacement to represent a moment in UTC. `Instant` has a resolution of [nanoseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanosecond), finer than the [milliseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Millisecond) of `Date`.

> when I create a Date() object and print it using toString(), it displays the local time

There are *many* problems with the legacy date-time classes. One is the poor naming, as mentioned above. Another is the well-intentioned by unfortunate design decision made that `Date::toString` should dynamically apply the JVM’s current default time zone to adjust from UTC while generating the text. This bad decision has caused no end of confusion and pain to Java programmers, as it creates the illusion that `java.util.Date` has a time zone assigned.

As an aside… Even worse, the `java.util.Date` *does* have a time zone, but buried deep in its source code with no accessor getter/setter methods. But that zone does affect some behavior such as determining equality between objects of this class. Confusing? Yes. As I said, these legacy date-time classes are riddled with poor design decisions.

> If this is not the right way to print it, what should it be so I would get the UTC time?

The right way is to avoid the `Date` class entirely. Use only the *java.time* classes instead.

➥ To get the current moment in UTC, use [`Instant.now`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html#now()).

```
Instant instant = Instant.now() ;
```

Tip: If you want to alter the time for the purpose of artificial testing, pass an alternate [`Clock`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/Clock.html) to [`Instant.now( Clock )`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html#now(java.time.Clock)).

To generate a `String` with text representing the value of that `Instant` in standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format, simply call `toString`. Fortunately this class does *not* inject a time zone like `Date` does. The [`Instant::toString`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html#toString()) method tells the simple truth, text of the moment in UTC.

```
String output = instant.toString() ;
```

> 2019-12-03T10:15:30.032163Z

Be clear that date-time objects such as `Instant` do not have a “format”. Only text representing the value of those objects have a format. The text and the date-time object are distinct and separate from each other. A date-time object can generate such text, and can parse such text, but is not actually the text.

If you need flexibility in generating text in other formats, apply a `ZoneOffset` to get a `OffsetDateTime` object, or apply a `ZoneId` to get a a `ZonedDateTime` object. Apply a `DateTimeFormatter` object to generate the text.

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Answer (score 1):

A `java.util.Date` object simply represents the number of ***milliseconds*** since the standard base time known as "the epoch", namely January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 GMT (or UTC). Since it does not hold any timezone information, its **[`toString`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Date.html#toString--)** function applies the JVM's timezone to return a `String` in the format, `EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy`, derived from this ***milliseconds*** value. To get the `String` representation of the `java.util.Date` object in a different format and timezone, you need to use `SimpleDateFormat` with the desired format and the applicable timezone e.g.

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.TimeZone;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Date date = new Date();

        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX", Locale.ENGLISH);

        sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/New_York"));
        String strDateNewYork = sdf.format(date);
        System.out.println(strDateNewYork);

        sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Etc/UTC"));
        String strDateUtc = sdf.format(date);
        System.out.println(strDateUtc);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2021-06-20T09:43:39.517-04:00
2021-06-20T13:43:39.517Z
```

[<kbd>ONLINE DEMO</kbd>](https://ideone.com/FYlPGt)

## *java.time*

The `java.util` Date-Time API and their formatting API, `SimpleDateFormat` are outdated and error-prone. It is recommended to stop using them completely and switch to the [modern Date-Time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-Date-Time.html)<sup>*</sup>.

Also, quoted below is a notice from the [home page of **Joda-Time**](https://www.joda.org/joda-time/):

> Note that from Java SE 8 onwards, users are asked to migrate to java.time (JSR-310) - a core part of the JDK which replaces this project.

**Solution using `java.time`, the modern Date-Time API:**

```
import java.time.Instant;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Instant now = Instant.now();
        System.out.println(now);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2021-06-20T13:37:42.174352Z
```

[<kbd>ONLINE DEMO</kbd>](https://ideone.com/55lNQp)

An [`Instant`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) represents an instantaneous point on the timeline in [UTC](https://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/timezone/utc). The `Z` in the output is the [timezone designator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Time_zone_designators) for a zero-timezone offset. It stands for Zulu and specifies the `Etc/UTC` timezone (which has the timezone offset of `+00:00` hours).

Learn more about the modern Date-Time API from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

---

<sup>* For any reason, if you have to stick to Java 6 or Java 7, you can use [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) which backports most of the *java.time* functionality to Java 6 & 7. If you are working for an Android project and your Android API level is still not compliant with Java-8, check [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) and [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).</sup>