# Java Calendar: getting time for the timezone

Tags: java, date, calendar

The following works (shows UTC time)

```
TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
System.out.println(new Date());
```

but this doesn't (shows local time)

```
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
    System.out.println(cal.getTime());
    System.out.println(new Date());
```

Is there something simple, that I'm missing?

Comment: The `java.util` Date-Time API and their formatting API, `SimpleDateFormat` are outdated and error-prone. It is recommended to stop using them completely and switch to the [modern Date-Time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-Date-Time.html).  Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68056391/10819573) which uses the modern Date-Time API.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're printing out the result of [`Date.toString()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#toString%28%29), which *always* uses the default time zone.

I suggest you use [`DateFormat`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html) instead, which is better suited for formatting dates. `Date.toString` is really only suitable for debugging - it provides no control over the format.

Alternatively, use [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sf.net) for all your date and time operations - it's a much better API to start with :)

Comment: I just wondered, who will be the first one to offer Joda Time?

Answer (score 3):

To get date, formatted for other timezone, use SimpleDateFormat and set timezone in it (by default, it uses local timezone).

Try this way:

```
SimpleDateFormat f = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:SS Z");
f.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
System.out.println(f.format(cal.getTime()));
System.out.println(new Date());
```

Comment: I need to convert this string date to Date date and if i do, it again picks up the local timezone. Is there any solution for this?