# Date getTime() from Calendar in specific timezone

Tags: java, date, datetime

I have this code below:

```
Date now = CalendarUtils.getCalendar(getDefaultTimeZone())
                .getTime();
```

The CalendarUtils class has the below methods

```
public static Calendar getCalendar(final TimeZone tz) {
    return getCalendar(CalendarUtils.getDate(), tz);
}

public static Calendar getCalendar(final Date time, final TimeZone tz) {
    final GregorianCalendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar();
    calendar.setTimeZone(tz);
    calendar.setTime(time);
    return calendar;
}

public static Date getDate() {
    return CalendarUtils.getDate(System.currentTimeMillis());
}
```

Where the getDefaultTimeZone() returns a timezone object in a specific timezone. Let's say Europe/Madrid.

However my application is running on a server in Rome.

The problem is that the code above is used to get the local time of Madrid. So at 12:30 am in Rome on Aug. 8th it is still 11:30 pm Aug. 7th in Madrid.

When I use

```
Date startOfDay = DateUtils.truncate(now, Calendar.DATE);
```

I would expect Aug. 7th 00:00:00 instead I get Aug 8th 00:00:00

I have read how Date returns the Millis from the Epoch but I would expect that it would return the millis from the Epoch of the date I ask from the Calendar.

When I use the query below at 12:30 am Aug 8th Rome time  utilizing the two dates (now and startOfDay) I get results for the 8th of Aug instead the 7th (which is the local time in Madrid).

```
 public BigInteger getSumForDates(Date fromDate, Date toDate) {

    Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
    BigInteger sum;
    try{
        sum = (BigInteger)session
            .createSQLQuery(
                    "SELECT SUM(column) FROM table 
                     WHERE (column2 at time zone vas_tz()) >=:fromDate 
                   AND (column2 at time zone vas_tz()) < :toDate")
                  .setTimestamp("fromDate", fromDate)
                  .setTimestamp("toDate", toDate).uniqueResult();
    }catch (final HibernateException e){
        LOGGER.error(e.getMessage());
        throw new ProjectRuntimeException();
    }finally{
        session.close();

    }
```

**EDIT**

The DateUtils is the one from `package org.apache.commons.lang.time;`

```
public static Date truncate(Date date, int field) {
    if (date == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("The date must not be null");
    }
    Calendar gval = Calendar.getInstance();
    gval.setTime(date);
    modify(gval, field, MODIFY_TRUNCATE);
    return gval.getTime();
}
```

When I say to return the millis for the date I have asked the `Calendar` for, I meant that if the calendar has supplied Aug 7th 11:30 pm (since I provided a timezone) then I would expect the millis from the Epoch until Aug 7th 11:30 adjusted for that timezone. Is this an incorrect expectation?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java Calendar: getting time for the timezone](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7482956/java-calendar-getting-time-for-the-timezone)

Comment: @DavidPostill That question had more to do with printing a correctly formatted date which is a bit different from what I am looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have read how Date returns the Millis from the Epoch but I would expect that it would return the millis from the Epoch of the date I ask from the Calendar.

Then your expectation is incorrect - or you're not expressing your expectation clearly. There's only one Unix epoch: it's midnight *UTC*. A `Date` has no concept of a time zone - it's *just* the number of milliseconds since the Unix epoch.

It's not clear what your `DateUtils` class is, but anything which claims to truncate a `Date` to a day without specifying a time zone is somewhat dubious.

I would *strongly* advise you to use [Joda Time](http://joda.org/joda-time) or the Java 8 `java.time` classes - they're *much* simpler to work with than `java.util.*`. If you *must* use `java.util.Date` and `java.util.Calendar`, you'll need to work out which time zone you're interested, and specify that appropriately - using `Calendar`, not `Date` - when performing operations such as "truncate to day".

Comment: Thank you for your input. However I need to understand what is wrong with the code I have used since this kind of Date/Calendar usage is repeated in many places in an application I have inherited and if this part is wrong then others will be also.

Comment: @idipous: well you haven't shown us half the code (e.g. DateUtils.truncate) so we can't help you correct that. I suspect you'll need to go through all date handling code *very* carefully... ideally replacing it with Joda or java.time as you go.

Comment: @idipous: Okay. Well you'd need to write an overload taking a time zone, and set the time zone on the calendar. Otherwise it will use the system default time zone.

Comment: so you mean `Calendar gval = Calendar.getInstance();` is to blame here right? I thought that `gval.setTime(date)` would take care of that but then again date is just millis sine the epoch in UTC. Then what does it do there? What is its function?

Comment: @idipous: I don't have time to answer now. But just remember that a Date is an instant in time, whereas a day depends on a time zone.

Comment: Thank you. Using the truncate with the Calendar parameter instead of the date did the trick. Now I got the answer to my last question as well.